# Divide $n$ students in 4 groups

Tags: combinatorics

In class, a teacher proposes four different projects, which can be done by one or more students. In how many ways can $n$ students be grouped in four groups, in such a way that every student participates in exactly one group and every project is done by exactly one group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first assume that students are not distinguishable (i.e. it doesn't matter if student $A$ or student $B$ participates in project $X$, only the amount of students which participate in the project matters). Since every project must be chosen, at least one student is assigned to each project. Then, we must must divide the $n-4$ remaining students over the four projects, which is essentially a [stars and bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). The number of ways in which to do this equals:

$${n-4+4-1 \choose 4-1} = {n-1 \choose 3}$$

If students are distinguishable, the result is different. Each student can select one of the four projects, so the total number of possible arrangements is $4^n$. However, one project must be assigned to at least one student. Let us determine the number of ways $F(k)$ in which only $k$ projects are chosen by these students:

$$F(1) = {4 \choose 1} 1^n = 4$$
$$F(2) = {4 \choose 2} \bigg(2^n - {2 \choose 1} 1^n\bigg) = 6 \cdot 2^n - 12$$
$$F(3) = {4 \choose 3} \bigg(3^n - {3 \choose 2} \bigg(2^n - {2 \choose 1} 1^n\bigg) - {3 \choose 1} 1^n\bigg) = 4 \cdot 3^n - 12 \cdot 2^n + 12$$
$$F(4) = 4^n - F(3) - F(2) - F(1) = 4^n - 4 \cdot 3^n + 6 \cdot 2^n - 4$$

For $n=4$, $F(4) = 24 = 4!$ which makes sense, since the first student can choose one of the four projects, the second student one of the remaining three, the third student on of the remaining two and the last student the only remaining project.